# Parse email info from text file

Tags: python, parsing

I have updated this code. Right now this code will get the first name, last name, and email from email addresses in a text file. I just need to add a counter that counts the number of unique domain names!
so for example:

```
taco.salad@tacos.com
burrito.fest@burrito.com
asmith@tacos.com
```

would return this:

```
taco.salad@tacos.com
first name: taco
last name: salad
domain: tacos.com

burrito.fest@burrito.com
first name: burrito
last name: fest
domain: burrito.com

asmith@tacos.com
first name: a
last name: smith
domain: tacos.com

number of emails found:
3
number of unique domains found:
2
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re

count = 0
fname = input('Enter a filename: ')

afile = open((fname), "rt")
for email in afile:
  if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  email):

    print("Found email:" + email)
    count+=1
    split_email = email.split('@')

    name = str(split_email[0])
    for letter in name:
        if "." not in name: 
            splitname = ""
        else:
            splitname = name.split('.')



    try:
        print("First name:" + splitname[0])
        print("Last name:" + splitname[1])
        print ("Domain:" + split_email[1])
    except:
        print("First name:" + name[0])
        print("First name:" + name[1:])
        print ("Domain:" + split_email[1])




    print("\n")
print ("Number of emails found: ")    
print (count)
input('Press ENTER key to continue: ')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.examples.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# You can switch this with your file data
example_emails = ['testUwuw@gmail.com', 'FirstLast@email.com', 'FLast@email.com']

for email in example_emails:
  if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  email):
    print("Found email:" + email)
    # Split string on char @
    # Example input:
    # testUwu@gmail.com
    # Output:
    # ['testUwu', 'gmail.com']
    split_email = email.split('@')
    # Split string on uppercase letters
    credentials = re.findall('[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*', split_email[0])
    print("First name:" + credentials[0])
    print("Last name:" + credentials[1])
    print ("Domain:" + split_email[1])
    # Newline for nicer output formatting
    print("\n")
```

Example output:

```
Found email:FirstLast@email.com
First name:First
Last name:Last
Domain:email.com


Found email:FLast@email.com
First name:F
Last name:Last
Domain:email.com
```

This example code will work only and only with your 2 email formats.

Note that you should probably use some exception handling in case some other formats slip in, example `Test@gmail.com` will throw IndexError exception because program expects 2 uppercase words. Also on words with more than 2 uppercase letters the code will ignore all letters past second uppercase.

Those are some of the notes I would like you to be aware of, if you're positive that you only have those 2 formats this should work fine.

Comment: I actually should have the code split where it reads lowercase and splits them that way. I only had caps in the examples to show the format of the names.

Comment: @DakotaV what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, I updated the main post. That was my bad for using that format. I need the format to be firstlast@email.com or flast@email.com. I was just using the caps to make it easier to read.

Comment: If it's a all lowercase string then there's no way to differentiate first name from last name, there could be billions of combinations.

Comment: I was thinking of either separating it by the "." if its there, creating the first and last name. Or if there is no "." then it would remove the first letter, and then add then add the last name. Im not sure how I would do that though.

Comment: There, fixed it. Just need a unique domain counter. Thank you for the help.